# Kafka REST API source connector with authentication header

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-rest

I need to create kafka source connector  for REST API with Header authentication like
curl   -H "Authorization: Basic " -H "clientID:  "    "https:< url for source> " .
I am using apache kafka , I used connector class com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.HttpSourceConnector
Here is my json file for connector

```
{
    "name": "rest_data6",
    "config": {
           "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
           "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
           "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
           "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
            "connector.class": "com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.HttpSourceConnector",
           "tasks.max": "1",
            "http.request.headers": "Authorization: Basic <key1>",
            "http.request.headers": "clientID: <key>",
             "http.request.url": "https:<url for source ?",
           "kafka.topic": "mysqltopic2"
    }
}
```

Also I tried with   "connector.class": "com.tm.kafka.connect.rest.RestSourceConnector", My joson file as below

```
"name": "rest_data2",
"config": {

       "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
       "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
       "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
       "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
       "connector.class": "com.tm.kafka.connect.rest.RestSourceConnector",
       "rest.source.poll.interval.ms": "900",
       "rest.source.method": "GET",
       "rest.source.url":"URL of source ",
       "tasks.max": "1",
       "rest.source.headers": "Authorization: Basic <key> , clientId :<key2>",
"rest.source.topic.selector": "com.tm.kafka.connect.rest.selector.SimpleTopicSelector",
"rest.source.destination.topics":  "mysql1"

}

}
```

But no hope . Any idea how to GET  REST API data with authentication . My authentication parameter is
Authorization: Basic  and Authorization: Basic  .

Just for mention both the file are working with REST API without authentication , once I added authentication parameter then wither connector status is failed or It produce ":"Cannot route. Codebase/company is invalid"" message in topic.
Can any one suggest what is way to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mailed to original developer to Cástor Rodríguez. As per his solution I modified my json

Put header into a single form and it works

```
{
    "name": "rest_data6",
    "config": {
           "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
           "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
           "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
           "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
            "connector.class": "com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.HttpSourceConnector",
           "tasks.max": "1",
            "http.request.headers": "Authorization: Basic <key1>, clientID: <key>"
             "http.request.url": "https:<url for source ?",
           "kafka.topic": "mysqltopic2"
    }
}
```

[image]